# How to clone Ubuntu 18.04 drive to drive?

Tags: clone, disk-image, cloning

I recently upgraded my storage to a bigger nvme drive and I wanted to clone my existing drive on to it. I read suggestions about clonezilla (that didn't work for me) and using the dd command.

I haven't tried the dd command because my understanding is that it converts and copies all the files and will not work properly if my drive size doesn't match. My drive size is 512 gb and 960 gb. How does dd handle partition size and what exactly is it converting?

Clonezilla didn't work for me because after the prompt to select the drive to clone, it didn't display any of my 2 nvme drives. I have them both connected to the mobo along with 2 other storage drives. The storage drives were the only options to pick from.

Please let me know how to clone Ubuntu 18.04 drive to drive. One other thing, my original install wasn't setup with drive encryption is it possible to change that while cloning to a new drive?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FWIW: Encrypting, if you do not have a very specific reason for turning it on; then don't. I have a number of years experience with computers and have so far not seen a reason to encrypt disks. Check before: How does data recovery software handle encrypted disks? Can you 'dd' an encrypted disk without side effects? -- Now: A laptop often used outside your home/office could be one reason to encrypt.

Comment: Yes, it's for my laptop. In case something happens to it I don't want someone to have easy access to my data. That's the reason I decided to encrypt this time. How can I encrypt the new drive and copy the old drive to it? Any way to setup encryption on the drive than use dd to copy/clone?

Comment: Sorry, someone else will have to answer that. I suggest you enter a new question, or search for relevant Q/A's - there probably is some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible method:

1. Boot a live disk *(e.g. ubuntu installation media - in "try" mode, the source disk is best kept unmounted, not in use)* and run this from there:
2. Use `dd` to transfer the data. dd will not convert anything unless
   you tell it to do so, see the output of `dd --help`. *The copy (at destination) needs/occupies the same space as the source data, larger available space at destination is ok.*
3. Use e.g. `gparted` *(`sudo apt-get install gparted`)* to move and resize partitions at will, so that available space gets used.

The exact commands to use will depend on your hardware.

Notes:
`lsblk` - will show available disks and devices.
`dd` - does what you tell it to do... it does not do mind-reading to correct your logical errors, so make sure you **actually have typed exactly what you intend to do**.
`gparted` - works best with simple jobs at a time (personal experience), e.g. move one partion, execute job, move another partition, execute job, resize second partition, execute job. Note the green tick - click it to execute the defined job.

Comment: thank you, will try this in the next few days when I get a chance.